# Reusing the activation_token and activation_digest when a user changes their email

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My User model is based off of [Hartl's Rails Tutorial.](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/account_activation) Here is the [github page for the User model](https://github.com/mhartl/sample_app_3rd_edition/blob/master/app/models/user.rb)

When a user changes their email address, I want them to go back through the account validation process. Is it possible to reuse `attr_accessor: :activation_token` and `column: activation_digest`?

I tried to create the following method:

```
user.rb
#the goal here is to reset activation_token and activation_digest
def deactivated
    update_attribute(:activated, false)
end

def create_activation_digest
    self.activation_token = User.new_token
    self.activation_digest = User.digest(activation_token)
end    

# These below are all pre-existing!

def send_activation_email
    UserMailer.account_activation(self).deliver_now
end


def User.digest(string)
  cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                BCrypt::Engine.cost
  BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
end

def User.new_token
  SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end

def authenticated?(attribute, token)
    digest = send("#{attribute}_digest")
    return false if digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(digest).is_password?(token)
end

def activate
    update_attribute(:activated,    true)
    update_attribute(:activated_at, Time.zone.now)
end  

users_controller

# My Code
if !params[:user][:email].blank? 
  if @user.authenticate(params[:user][:current_password])
    params[:user].delete :current_password
    @user.update_attributes(email_user_params)
      if @user.save 
        @user.deactivated
        @user.create_activation_digest
        @user.send_activation_email
        log_out
        flash[:notice] = "Please check email pal"
        redirect_to root_url
      else 
        flash[:danger] = "Email Update Failed"
        redirect_to edit_user_email_path(@user)
      end
  else 
    flash[:danger] = "Password entered was incorrect"
    redirect_to edit_user_email_path(@user)
  end  
end  

#pre-existing 
class AccountActivationsController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    if user && !user.activated? && user.authenticated?(:activation, params[:id])
      user.activate
      log_in user 
      flash[:success] = "Account activated!"
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Invalid activation link"
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end
end
```

This sends an activation email and it changes the `activated` attribute however when clicking on the link, it just gives me the fail error message from the `account_activations_controller`, no clues from heroku what causes the error.

here is the mailer

```
Hi <%= @user.name %>,

<%= edit_account_activation_url(@user.activation_token, email: @user.email) %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not working because I had the method listed as private. Making it public allowed the code above to work.